# Unable to select/click second and last element on mouse hover in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

1. Below is the screenshot of the mouse hover event.

[Style type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2UsR.png)

It is triggered only on mouse hover. Currently, I'm able to read the Style Type Text. I can select the first element without any issues, however, I'm unable to click the second and last element (Categorized and Graduated ).

2. UI Code for reference.

[UI code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Lb2.png)

3. Below is the Selenium code for reference.

   ```
    static void styletype() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    String sname = null;
    // select style type
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@src = 'assets/images/down_arrow.svg']"));
    action.moveToElement(menu).perform();
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    List<WebElement> rowsList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'dropdown-item')]"));
    for (WebElement element : rowsList) {
        try {
            sname = element.getText();
            // System.out.println("File Type is : " + sname);
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Layer Stype Type : '" + sname + "'",
                    "Do you want to continue", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if (result == 0) {
                element.click();
                break;
            }
            action.moveToElement(menu).perform();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
   ```

   }

Comment: Please clarify what the variable "frame" is and reformat you code so it is readable. Thank you.

Comment: What is the output of this line `System.out.println("File Type is : " + sname);` ?

Comment: System.out.println("File Type is : " + sname); prints all style types.  Frame is Jframe for user to select the desired option "static JFrame frame = new JFrame();"

Comment: Managed to resolve the problem